# wpf combobox display 1st item from list

Tags: wpf, vb.net, binding, observablecollection

i have a combobox bound to an ObservableCollection:-

```
<ComboBox Name="combo" ItemsSource="{Binding Things}" SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged" >
```

in the code behind I have

```
Dim thingArray = New ObservableCollection(Of Things)   
Me.combo.DataContext = Me.thingArray
```

Assume thingArray is initialized to 5 `Thing` objects and `Thing` has a `toString()` implementation. I want to display the first item `Thing(0)` by default on the ComboBox. How do i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`If Me.thingArray.Count > 0 Then Me.combo.SelectedIndex = 0`

Comment: Hah, thanks, that was easy enough, can't believe i didn't see that! i tried it in the loaded() method but it didn't show up but later saw the same thing in the XAML & it works.  
Prior to this I messed around too much with comboboxItem & got even more confused